# Enable/Disable login button from ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, button, android-livedata

guys  I have login page with 2 editText field (username, password) and with 1 button (Submit)

I want to enable Submit button when something is written is both editText.

I created two LiveData variable

```
val _userName = MutableLiveData<String>()
val userName: LiveData<String>
    get() = _userName

val _password = MutableLiveData<String>()
val password: LiveData<String>
    get() = _password
```

this is my submit button in xml

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/uSubmit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/log_in_button_text"
            android:enabled="@{authViewModel.isSubmitButtonEnabled()}"
            android:onClick="@{_ -> authViewModel.uUserLogin()}"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordInputLayout" />
```

I tried to wrote this code in viewModel to enable button when something is written in userName field

```
var isSubmitButtonEnabled = (Transformations.map(userName) {
            it.isNotEmpty()
        })
```

and this works fine. Now I want to enable button when in both userName and password variable is something written.  How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `viewmodel` to achieve this. You can simply use only `xml` + `databinding` to get it right.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/uSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/log_in_button_text"
        android:enabled="@{!PASSWORD_EDITTEXT_ID_IN_CAMEL_CASE.text.toString().isEmpty() &amp;& !USERNAME_EDITTEXT_ID_IN_CAMEL_CASE.text.toString().isEmpty()}"
        ... />
```

Comment: Wow, thanks man, I didn't know that, also I was searched everywhere but couldn't found something like this, its very useful. thank you